# how to return array of values from js function

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

I am using [social-auth-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/social-auth-plugin) for phonegap and I have this function:

```
window.socialAuth.accessFacebook(function success() {}, function error() {})
```

in the description of this plugin it says:

> If permission is granted, returns account. If not granted, it returns "Error"

I tried the function like this

```
window.socialAuth.accessFacebook(function success() {alert("success")}, function error() {})
```

now how can I return the array of values ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Does it work and what does it alerts? The arg may be the account you want. (Fail)

```
window.socialAuth.accessFacebook(function success(arg) {alert(arg)}, function error() {})
```

Another try:

```
alert( window.socialAuth.accessFacebook(function success() {}, function error() {}));
```

Comment: @lina Then does this works? `alert( window.socialAuth.accessFacebook(function success() {}, function error() {}));`

Comment: it is alerted undefined :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var accountArray;
window.socialAuth.accessFacebook(function success(account) {
  alert("success");
  accountArray = account; // optionally you can return account and set accountArray equal to the function's return.
}, function error() {
})

alert(accountArray);
```

Just give your success function a parameter to stick the account into.

Comment: it is not alerting anything even the success msg

Comment: but you ARE getting the "success" alert?